# Right-continuity and volume of balls

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d,\mathfrak{m})$ be a metric measure space with $\mathfrak{m}$ a non-negative Radon measure. Set $v(r):=\mathfrak{m}(\bar{B}_r(x_0))$ be the volume of the closed ball with radius $r>0$ and center $x_0\in X$.

$v$ is right-continuous and non-decreasing with at most countably many discontinuities. In particular, there will be arbitrarily small $r>0$ and $\delta>0$ such that $v$ is continuous on the interval $[r,(1+\delta)r[$.

Now comes a point in the paper I am reading that I don't understand: "Furthermore, given $r$ and $\delta$ by successive subdivision of the interval $[r,(1+\delta)r]$, one can construct a sequence $(r_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of points in $[r,(1+\delta)r]$ with $$0\leq\frac{1}{2^{-n}\delta r}[v((1+2^{-n}\delta)r)-v(r)]\leq\frac{1}{\delta r}[v((1+\delta)r)-v(r)]=:C."$$
How to derive the middle inequality? It seems to come just from the right continuity and non-decreasing property of $v$ but then it would seem that every function like that is locally Lipschitzian, which is false. What am I missing?